# Adding a attribute to json file

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I have a json file of the format

```
{"latitude":28.488069,"longitude":-81.407208,"data":[{"time":1462680000,"summary":"Clear"},{"time":1462683600,"summary":"Clear",},{"time":1462694400,"summary":"Clear"}]}}
```

I want to add id attribute inside data

```
val result = jsonfile

val Jsonobject = Json.parse(result).as[JsObject]

val res = Jsonobject ++ Json.obj("id" -> 1234)

println(Json.prettyPrint(res))
```

the output should be

```
{"latitude":28.488069,"longitude":-81.407208,"data":[{"time":1462680000,"summary":"Clear","id":"1234"},{"time":1462683600,"summary":"Clear","id":"1235"},{"time":1462694400,"summary":"Clear","id":"1236"}]}
```

but my output is

```
{"latitude":28.488069,"longitude":-81.407208,"data":[{"time":1462680000,"summary":"Clear"},{"time":1462683600,"summary":"Clear",},{"time":1462694400,"summary":"Clear"}]},"id":"1234"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things missing in your code. In your expected output, the ID is incremented, how do you expect to just add `"id" -> 1234` and have it automatically incremented ?

Anyway, you have to loop through the elements in `data` and set it for each one of them. Something like this works:

```
    val j = Json.parse(result).as[JsObject]
    val res = j ++ Json.obj("data" ->  
      // get the 'data' array and loop inside
          (j \ "data").as[JsArray].value.zipWithIndex.map {  
      // zipWithIndex lets us use the index to increment the ID
      case (x,i) => x.as[JsObject] +  ("id" , JsString((1234 + i).toString)) })
    println(Json.prettyPrint(res))

{
  "latitude" : 28.488069,
  "longitude" : -81.407208,
  "data" : [ {
    "time" : 1462680000,
    "summary" : "Clear",
    "id" : "1234"
  }, {
    "time" : 1462683600,
    "summary" : "Clear",
    "id" : "1235"
  }, {
    "time" : 1462694400,
    "summary" : "Clear",
    "id" : "1236"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.. actually i am going to assign id to a variable which would take data(a column) from a flat file